# Find value based off multiple for loops

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take a part number from one sheet, find it in another sheet, then for the cells that correspond to tomorrow's date copy the quantity of parts for that specific part number plus two weeks out which is the resize. The code is starting to get really messy and I'm getting confused as to why it's not working. Currently I'm getting an error on cilrow = cil.rows with a mismatch.

```
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim cul As Range
    Dim cil As Range
    Dim cilrow As Long
    Dim culcol As Long
    Dim wkbOrig As Workbook
    Dim wkbShape As Workbook
    Dim shtShape As Worksheet
    
    Set wkbOrig = ThisWorkbook
    Set wkbShape = Workbooks("SHAPE Detailed coverage tracking WK" & WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum(Date))
    Set shtShape = wkbShape.Worksheets("Detail coverage tracking")
    
        For Each cel In wkbOrig.Sheets(2).Range("C3:C4,C9:C14")
            For Each cil In shtShape.Range("H6:H11")
                If Left(cel, 10) = cil.Value Then
                    cilrow = cil.Rows
                    For Each cul In shtShape.Range("5:5")
                        If cul.Value = Date + 1 Then
                            culcol = cul.Column
                            Range(Cells(cilrow, culcol)).Resize(, 14).Copy
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: cil.rows is a range, cil.row would return a long

Answer (score 0):

You can do less looping if you use `Match()`.

Untested:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim cel As Range, wkbShape As Workbook, shtShape As Worksheet
    Dim wkbOrig As Workbook, dateCol As Variant, matchRow As Variant
    Dim rngSrch As Range
    
    Set wkbOrig = ThisWorkbook
    'best to include the file extension in the workbook name...
    Set wkbShape = Workbooks("SHAPE Detailed coverage tracking WK" & _
                             WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum(Date))
    Set shtShape = wkbShape.Worksheets("Detail coverage tracking")
    
    'try to match the date...
    dateCol = Application.Match(CLng(Date + 1), shtShape.Rows(5), 0)
    If IsError(dateCol) Then 'date not matched?
        MsgBox "Tomorrow's date not found on Row6 of " & shtShape.Name, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set rngSrch = shtShape.Range("H6:H11")
    
    For Each cel In wkbOrig.Sheets(2).Range("C3:C4,C9:C14").Cells
        matchRow = Application.Match(Left(cel.Value, 10), rngSrch, 0)
        If Not IsError(matchRow) Then
        
            rngSrch.Cells(matchRow).EntireRow.Cells(dateCol).Resize(1, 14).Copy 'to where ?
        
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```